# Figure out what button change was made using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am quite new to Javascript and have been trying to use Javascript within my ASP.NET MVC project.

I have a button that onclick changes e.g. from ON to OFF.  There are many of these buttons - one for each record. 
I want to figure out which change a button makes when pressed i.e did it become OFF or ON?

Currently, I am using an if statement to check the toggleClass, however, I don't believe this is the current approach and the statement does not result in True when required.

Here is some example code:

```
<a id="menu-toggle_@j" href="#" class="btn btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></a>
<script>
    $('#menu-toggle_@j').click(function () {
         $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-down');
             $(if('#menu-toggle_@j').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-down')){
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Got some sample code to show? A fiddle would be great

Comment: You could check the text of the button?

Comment: I've added some sample code in the question.  Hope that helps.  The issue is with the if statement.

Comment: $(if('#menu... ? Did you mean if($(this).toggleClass... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily retrieve a button's status if it is determined by a class. Just use `$.hasClass()`:

```js
$('button').click(toggleBtn);
$('#getEveryStatus').click(getEveryStatus);

function toggleBtn(){
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    
    if($(this).hasClass('on')){
        $(this).next('.status')
               .text('The button above is now ON.');
    } else {
        $(this).next('.status')
               .text('The button above is now OFF.');
    }
}

function getEveryStatus(){
    var list = '';
    $('button').each(function(i){
     list += 'Button #' + i + ' is ' + ($(this).hasClass('on')? 'ON':'OFF') + '.\n';
    });
    
    alert(list);
}
```

```css
button{
    width: 4em;
    height: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    background: #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background .2s ease;
    transition: background .2s ease;
}

button.on{
    background: #63e63e;
}

button:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 3em;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    margin-top: -1em;
    margin-left: -1em;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 2em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-transition: left .2s ease;
    transition: left .2s ease;
}
button.on:before{
    left: 1em;
}

#getEveryStatus{
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button></button>
<p class="status">The button above is now OFF.</p>

<button></button>
<p class="status">The button above is now OFF.</p>

<p id="getEveryStatus">Click here to get every status</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! I love the look of this solution and does everything I need :)

Comment: @fuzzii Good! Sorry, I did not have your code sample at the time I wrote this, but if you need help applying it to your code, don't hesitate!

Comment: if I add the line if ($(this).hasClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up')) then the previously working $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-down'); no longer changes the view.  I am adding the if statement immediately after the statement to change the toggleClass.

Comment: If the `glyphicon` class is always there, you should not include it in `hasClass` or `toggleClass` (Just like 'button', in my case, this is never changed). If that does not solve it, please create a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luugd6kb/) with enough code to reproduce the problem. I _think_ you should do `if ($(this).find('li').hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-up'))`